# Please support Furigana in mobile app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, mobile-app

Japanese has **Furigana**. Furigana is how to read.
Example:

```
[日本人]{にほんじん}
```

Result:
[image: Result]
(日本人 → Japanese)
See also:[How should I format my questions on Japanese Language SE?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/806/how-should-i-format-my-questions-on-japanese-language-se)

---

but Furigana does not support mobile. So the example is displayed in the following manner:

[image: Result in Mobile]

This is bit hard to read. Please support Furigana in mobile-app.